# I need to move a dived CSS module into the center of the page

Tags: html, css

I'm building a website for someone and they wanted the text and bulk of the information to be centered on the page. Problem is I can get everything contained in a  tag and then assign the class, but I can't get the whole thing to center. It always hangs to the left even if I apply centering to the div class.

I guess you could say that it is stuck on the left side of the page when I want everything to be centered. I would just make everything format larger but they want some space left in the background for the color and maybe some imagery later on. They haven't made up their minds.

[If you want to take a look here is the link where I'm building or testing stuff.](http://new-wav.com/mable/) I know the header and such needs to be re proportioned to fit with everything, but just as a frame of reference. Don't worry about the header, just know that I want the white text information area with the purple border to stay the same size, but just move to the center and if some one could tell me how to do that I would appreciate it greatly.

Comment: Can you respond which one is worked for you or still need solution?

Answer (score 1):

just add `margin: 0 auto;` to that class CSS, for this to work, that object needs to have a width

Answer (score 0):

```
<div align="center" class="stylex" style="margin:0 auto;width:606px">
<span class="heading"><strong>About The Book</strong></span><br>
<span class="stylez">Mable's Magic Spell</span> Features 28<br> 
  of the most commonly misspelled words by children.<br>
<br>
Through rhyming, a visual clue, or a word association,<br> 
<span class="stylez">Mable</span> and her dog <span class="stylez">Mixie</span> take a close look at these words.<br><img src="http://new-wav.com/mable/MableBookCover_small.jpg" class="img" width="457" height="550" align="middle"><br>
<span class="stylez">Mable's Magic Spell</span> is a book children should read many times.<br> Through repetition, children can succeed at spelling these everyday words.<p></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For your div set the css `margin: auto;`